# Getting AllowEdit to default to true for a listview with XAF+EF+Generics

Tags: entity-framework, devexpress, xaf

Generics aren't officially supported in XAF.
However I use them and love them.

```
[DomainComponent]
Public abstract class SalesHeader<TSalesLine> : BasicBO
    where TSalesLine : SalesProductTransactionLine
{

    public virtual BindingList<TSalesLine> Lines { get; set; } 

}

[DomainComponent]
public class SalesOrder : SalesHeader<SalesOrderLine>, ISalesHeader<SalesOrderLine>

{
    public SalesOrder()
    {
        Lines = new BindingList<SalesOrderLine>();
        ContactPerson = new Person();   //etc

    }
}
```

This creates a view in the model called SalesHeader[SalesOrderLine]_Lines_ListView
By default the AllowDelete and AllowNew property of this listview is True but the AllowEdit is false.

How do I get the AllowEdit to be true so that I don't have to use the model editor to override it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify model nodes in code using Generator Updaters.

This approach is not related to EF or Generics, however you can trigger this behaviour according to View ObjectType.

You may find the following references helpful:

[Devexpress xaf ungroup layout of inherited class. (programmaticaly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281143/devexpress-xaf-ungroup-layout-of-inherited-class-programmaticaly)

[How to: Create Additional ListView Nodes in Code via a Generator Updater](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument113315)

Comment: Thanks @ErikWitkowski.  I have included the exact code I needed in a separate answer  ( because answers format code better than comments)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented Erik's advice as

```
   public class CustomListViewItemUpdater : ModelNodesGeneratorUpdater<ModelViewsNodesGenerator>
    {
        public override void UpdateNode(ModelNode node)
        {
            var a = node["SalesHeader[SalesOrderLine]_Lines_ListView"];
            ((IModelListView)(a)).AllowEdit = true;
        }
    }
```